# HERE Maps JavaScript API zoomTo Bounding Box BUG

Tags: javascript, html, here-api

I observed some behavior in the HERE/Nokia Maps JavaScript API that appears to be a bug which manifests when zooming to a Container's bounding box.  This can be seen easily in the following example which I have tested in both Linux and Windows using a recent version of Firefox.

**bug.html**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="http://api.maps.nokia.com/2.2.3/jsl.js?with=maps"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type=button value=SHOW_GOOD_ZOOM onclick="good_zoom();" />
  <input type=button value=SHOW_BAD_ZOOM onclick="bad_zoom();" />
  <div id="mapContainer" >
   <script type="text/javascript" id="map" src="bug.js"></script>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**bug.js**

```
nokia.Settings.set("appId", "DemoAppId01082013GAL"); 
nokia.Settings.set("authenticationToken", "AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg");
var mapContainer = document.getElementById("mapContainer");
var container = new nokia.maps.map.Container();

var display = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapContainer, {
center: [0, 0],
zoomLevel: 1,
components: [ new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar() ]
});

var container = new nokia.maps.map.Container();
display.objects.add(container);

var point_in_idaho = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(43, -116 );
var bad_afghanistan_point = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(30, 64 );
var good_afghanistan_point = new nokia.maps.geo.Coordinate(30, 63 );

function bad_zoom() {
draw_and_zoom( point_in_idaho, bad_afghanistan_point );
}

function good_zoom() {
draw_and_zoom( point_in_idaho, good_afghanistan_point );
}

function draw_and_zoom( a, b ) {
container.objects.add( new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker( a ) );
container.objects.add( new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker( b ) );

alert("TL: " + container.getBoundingBox().topLeft + " / BR: " + container.getBoundingBox().bottomRight);
display.zoomTo( container.getBoundingBox() );
}
```

Open the bug.html in your browser and click SHOW_GOOD_ZOOM.  Note the two StandardMarkers on the screen and the alert which shows the Bounding Box's Top Left and Bottom Right coordinates:

TL: 43° 0' 0" N, 116° 0' 0" W / BR: 30° 0' 0" N, 63° 0' 0" E

Note that these correspond to Idaho (top left) and Afghanistan (bottom right).  When you click OK on the alert, you'll be zoomed in to a nice view of these two points on the map with the Atlantic Ocean in the middle.

Now reload the page and click SHOW_BAD_ZOOM.  The two StandardMarkers are in almost the same place: the point in Afghanistan has been moved one notch to the East (which you can see in the JavaScript code).  Note the Bounding Box's TL and BR here ....

TL: 43° 0' 0" N, 64° 0' 0" E / BR: 30° 0' 0" N, 116° 0' 0" W

Our Top Left is 43 North (near Idaho) but 64 East (near Afghanistan) and Bottom Right is "inverted" similarly.  What I would **expect** to see here after clicking OK is a reasonable zoom in, this time with the Pacific Ocean in the middle and both StandardMarkers shown.  What I get though, is the Pacfific Ocean dead center, but I'm zoomed into the maximum zoom level.  Now zoom out ~17 times and you'll see both Afghanastan (with a StandardMarker) and USA (w/o a StandardMarker) on the map!  Zoom out 2-3 more times and you'll see our Idaho marker way to the left of the map display.

This looks like a pretty clear bug to me.  When we zoom into to the Bounding Box of a Container, we obviously want to keep the items in the Container on the screen regardless of how we compute the Bounding Box.

What is **really** interesting here is that if I click SHOW_BAD_ZOOM and then (without reloading the page) click SHOW_GOOD_ZOOM, I get a good zoom/center.  Notice that Bounding Box coordinates here:

TL: 43° 0' 0" N, 116° 0' 0" W / BR: 30° 0' 0" N, 64° 0' 0" E

See how the "64" is on the bottom right now whereas in the "BAD" scenario, it was in the top left ...

Answer (score 0):

FIXED!  turns out I was using an older version (2.2.3) of the API.  With 2.5.4, this works as expected.